# How to make parent node can not selected in treeview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

How to make parent node  can not selected in treeview ?

If the node is "Parent" , it can not support select,
so I add code

```
 if (drv["isParent"].ToBool())
        {
            node.Selected = false;
        }
```

But not work? how to fix ?

```
        TreeNode node;
        var rows = dv.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r["ParentID"].ToString() == parentid);

        foreach (DataRow drv in rows.AsEnumerable())
        {
            //  DataRowView一行
            node = new TreeNode();
            node.Value = drv["NodeID"].ToString();
            node.Text = drv["Name"].ToString();
            if (drv["isParent"].ToBool())
            {
                node.Selected = false;
            }

            tnc.Add(node);

            if (drv["ObjectCode"].ToString() != "0")
            {
                InitTree(node.ChildNodes, node.Value);
            }
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (drv["isParent"].ToBool())
    {
   node.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None;
    }
```